# Mapping a Dictionary to a RestKit result

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, restkit

In a JSON model coming from a REST api I have a field that is supposed to be a Dictionary (a map, hashtable, call it whatever you want), e.g.:

```
"moduleMap": {
    "677e55b2-d80c-4b32-bcbb-e99074fbfcf6": {
         "id": "677e55b2-d80c-4b32-bcbb-e99074fbfcf6",
         "startTime": 1496054599227,
         "status": "ACTIVE"
    },
    "c20acde2-639f-4cb7-9b90-6d8d24c78166": {
         "id": "c20acde2-639f-4cb7-9b90-6d8d24c78166",
         "startTime": 1496054598997,
         "status": "UNAVAILABLE"
    }
}
```

As I understand RestKit (I am a newbie), usually this is mapped to an object in Swift. However, since the keys in this map are arbitrary uuids, I cannot write a class with these properties.

Can anybody point me to a direction of how to get this map into a Swift dictionary using RestKit mapping?

I would like to map it to `var moduleMap: [String:DomainObject]`, or at least `var moduleMap: NSMutableDictionary`. Also, I need it to be mappable back to the same JSON.

Comment: See [handling dynamic nesting attributes](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#handling-dynamic-nesting-attributes) in the RestKit docs.

Comment: I checked it out, thanks. Though it again creates a list of objects, where the key is mapped to the attributes of those objects. I need a dictionary - is there no direct way to do this?

Comment: Post what you want the output swift data structure to look like.

Comment: If you are not mapping moduleMap to an object, and you only want the raw JSON, then you don't need setup any mapping in RestKit. You might as well use Alamofire.

Comment: It's a domain object, a Dictionary where the key is the key of the JSON map, and the rest is mapped to Domain objects

Comment: I've no idea why you want to keep it as a dictionary, but if that's a requirement, then map it to an array then post process the resulting array back to a dictionary.